# Как в скрипт на bash через консоль передать строку параметром?

Tags: linux, bash

Подскажите как можно передать строку параметром для bash скрипта.

Сам скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
convert -font helvetica -fill white -pointsize 16 -draw 'text 10,50 "'$1'"' /var/www/img/display.jpg /var/www/img/comment.jpg
```

Пробовал вызвать так:

```
# ./display.sh "проверка текста"
```

И так:

```
# ./display.sh проверка\ текста
```

Скрипт воспринимает текст как два параметра, хочу разобраться как можно сделать, чтобы понимал как один параметр.

Comment: Пишете всё правильно, значит дело в самом скрипте

Comment: зачем-то кто-то нажал «тревогу» с предожением уточнить подробности вопроса. не требуется тут никаких уточнений. всё абсолютно прозрачно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash переменные вставляет всегда как один параметр внутри двойных кавычек и разбивает по пробелам если кавычек нет. У вас `$1` стоит вне кавычек. Нужно написать так:

```
convert -font helvetica -fill white -pointsize 16 -draw 'text 10,50 "'"$1"'"' /var/www/img/display.jpg /var/www/img/comment.jpg
```

Comment: Спасибо! Скрипт работает.

Comment: `'text 10,50 "'"$1"'"'` — это очень «жестокая» конструкция. по-моему, вполне достаточно и `"text 10.50 \"$1\""`

Comment: Согласен, затрудняет понимание.

Answer (score 1):

1. в одинарных кавычках должно работать: `ba.sh 'one two'`
2. в двойных кавычках: `ba.sh "one two"`
3. экранировать каждый пробел: `ba.sh один\ два`

Тестовый bash скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Input: $1"
```

Результаты тестов:

```
# ./ba.sh One Two
Input: One

# ./ba.sh 'One Two'
Input: One Two

# ./ba.sh "One Two"
Input: One Two

# ./ba.sh One\ Two 
Input: One Two
```

---

Ответ писал на первоначальную версию вопроса, потом не следил за обновлениями. Сам по себе ответ, может, кому-то пригодится. Но на поставленный вопрос он уже не отвечает.